# AJAX API Using GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a block of code that will fire off an API if a checkbox is checked. I've tested the API and it works. I had the form functioning before turning it into a widget. (at least I think I did??)

So here is the script that won't GET form values when checked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(jQuery || $)(function($) {
$('#survessay-form').on('submit', function() {
    // the jquery element of the form
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is('checked')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: `https://www.example.com/?cmd=api-co-reg&apik=ukp!BjItWgMi6Qk&Email=${$('#awf_field-95505011').val()}&FirstName=${$('#awf_field-95505010').val()}&aff_sid=emailcoreg&cmp=1320&cxid=242570`
        }).done(function(data) {
            data = data.result;
            $("#checkedmessage").html("<p>Thanks, " + data.name + ", you're now a Swagbucks participant!</p>");
            // continue to the confirmation page
        }).fail(function(data) {
            // verify data
            data = data.responseJSON;
            $("#errormessage").html("Error: Please check the format of your input");
        });
    }

    // stops probagation of event (doesn't submit the request to the php page)
    return false;
 });
});
```

So essential this should submit the API when the checkbox is checked and the user clicks the submit button but it continues on to the forms action method. Without submitting the request. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's hard to tell you what you're missing without you tell us what is/is not happening as you want it to. My first thought is that if this is a cross-domain request you're probably being blocked by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, my bad - thanks.

Comment: Oh let me clarify. When the checkkbox is selected and a user inputs their info it will AJAX/GET the url with there parameters and submit the API with the credentials. It will then continue to a thank you page. If the checkbox is not checked, no AJAX API GET before the thank you page.

Answer (score 0):

Use type: GET if the version is earlier than 1.9.0. Else use method: GET. More also, your URL suppose to start and end with " instead of the single quote since some of your parameter's value has the single quote. Below is the edited version of your code. Try to use your browser developer tools to debug your code.

```
 (function($) {
$('#survessay-form').on('submit', function() {
    // the jquery element of the form
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is('checked')) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://www.example.com/?cmd=api-co-reg&apik=ukp!BjItWgMi6Qk&Email=" + $('#awf_field-95505011').val() + "&FirstName=" + $('#awf_field-95505010').val() + "&aff_sid=emailcoreg&cmp=1320&cxid=242570",
success: function(data) {
            data = data.result;
            $("#checkedmessage").html("<p>Thanks, " + data.name + ", you're now a Swagbucks participant!</p>");
            // continue to the confirmation page
        }
      }).fail(function(data) {
            // verify data
            data = data.responseJSON;
            $("#errormessage").html("Error: Please check the format of your input");
    }

    // stops probagation of event (doesn't submit the request to the php page)
    return false;
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Actually, not correct on the quote marks.  OP is using the `\`` mark, which are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)